# You don’t have the proper credentials to access this page

Tags: guest-entries, validation

when trying to insert a guest entry i get the following response from craft:
You don’t have the proper credentials to access this page.

What can i do to avoid this and still insert the entry to craft? It needs to be an anonymous user.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you testing as a logged out user on the front-end?

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that you're testing as a logged-out user on the front-end of the site.  If you have an active Craft session, you could be getting a false positive error message.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue too, but there is another cause to this error. Go into Settings > Users > Settings in the Control Panel and ensure "Allow public registration?" is checked, it's unchecked by default.

Then it's also worth adding a conditional to the registration page to test if they are logged in or not, to ensure the error can never be triggered for a logged in user too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need is the guest entries plugin from Pixel & Tonic

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I worked locally, uploaded my templates to the server but did not import my local db to the remote db since I work with a team and needed to preserve the online, active db.

Therefore, I needed to recreate fields, sections, entries, and plugin settings on the server CMS, but I forgot to change the sectionId hidden  in my template to reflect what the new channel's section ID was.  On my local it was 13, but when I created it on the server, it was 12 and I just needed to change it in the code in the from like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="12">
```

Hope that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

More recently, you're required to install the Guest Entries plugin and configure it to allow public posts. Without said configuration, submissions will be rejected one way or another.

[image: configure the thing]